# How can I use python to read data on excel and then equate the cells to different variables eg. x, y, z etc

Tags: python, excel, csv, cell

New to python here,
How would I get python to read a row of cells, say 100, 200, 300 on excel and then make sure the code then equates x=100, y=200, z=300?

Answer (score -1):

If you can convert your `excel` to `csv` then you can do it without `pandas`.

```
import csv
rows = list(csv.reader(file(r'your_file.csv', 'r')))
row_0 = rows[0] ## first row
a,b,c = row_0[99],row_0[199],row_0[299] ### 100th, 200th and 300th element
```

Comment: What if I had other numbers like 203.67?

Comment: Rows and columns can only be integer. If you are talking about data in your excel then it'll be converted as it is to a csv file so it'll also work for non-integers.

Comment: What do the 99,199,299 mean then?

Comment: Also having trouble with the your_file.csv bit- do I need to save it somewhere specific?

Comment: its path to your csv file.

Comment: @user94863 99,199,299 are column numbers (indices in python start from 0). Any cell in excel is defined by its row and column number so first we selected a row and then corresponding column to get element of specific cell.

Comment: Wouldn't the column be 1, 2, 3 not 99, 199, 299 if I wanted the data from columns B, C, D in excel

Comment: Yes. If you want to extract data from B,C,D column.

Comment: Hmm... Seem to be getting this:
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

location: <unknown location>:-1

Error: Python script failed, check the message in the system console

Comment: It's because you are not using correct format for path. Can you post the line where you give path?

Comment: rows = list(csv.reader(file('C:\Users\aksha\Downloads\Blendercsvtest2.csv', 'r')))

Comment: use this with double backslash
`rows = list(csv.reader(file('C:\\Users\\aksha\\Downloads\\Blendercsvtest2.csv', 'r')))`

Comment: Now have this: NameError: name 'file' is not defined
Error: Python script failed, check the message in the system console

Comment: Try with forward slash.
`rows = list(csv.reader(file('C:/Users/aksha/Downloads/Blendercsvtest2.csv', 'r')))`
if it doesn't work, try this one
`rows = list(csv.reader(file(r'C:\Users\aksha\Downloads\Blendercsvtest2.csv', 'r')))`
or this one 
`rows = list(csv.reader(file('C:\\Users\aksha\Downloads\Blendercsvtest2.csv', 'r')))`

Comment: Got the same message unfortunately

Comment: Did you try all the above mentioned ways? If yes (which should have solved your problem) then simply move your csv file to the directory from where you are running your python program and use 

`rows = list(csv.reader(file('Blendercsvtest2.csv', 'r')))`

Comment: I did try those, kept getting the file error message. I'll have a go again and restarting the blender application etc I'll comment back here if there's some success or something comes up, thanks for the help

Comment: Right so I've now managed to get it to work, I'll post the code as an answer as its easier to see?

Answer (score -1):

Many Thanks to @Hozayfa El Rifai and @user_3pij for helping with this:

```
import csv

def read_csv(file_name='C:\\Users\\aksha\\Downloads\\Blendercsvtest2.csv'):
    with open(file_name) as csv_file:
        file = csv.reader(csv_file)
        return [i for i in file]

csvFileArray = read_csv()
row = csvFileArray[2]  # first row
x, y, z, l, m, n, p, q, r = row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4], row[5], row[6], row[7], row[8], row[9]

x = float(x)
y = float(y)
z = float(z)
l = float(l)
m = float(m)
n = float(n)
p = float(p)
q = float(q)
r = float(r)
```